# Is SpiderMonkey safe for running user-submitted scripts?

Tags: javascript, embedding

I've been searching for some way to permit users to write scripts in order to extend my application (written in Go) and so far, SpiderMonkey seems to be the best match.

Unfortunately, its website states that the last standalone release was of the version used in Firefox 4!

My question is if it is safe to run untrustworthy scripts with SpiderMonkey (I will use the operation and stack callbacks to prevent hanging, etc.) Or if there is a better alternative.

Comment: well, not really answering your question, but the website actually states, that it is **largely** the same engine as in FF4. To get a current Spidermonkey build, you can always build directly from moz-central. But if you only want to embed Spidermonkey, I generally go for the XULRunner SDK of a released version like [14.01](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/14.0.1/sdk/). That should give you a stable modern Spidermonkey.

Comment: @CodeSalad: hm, interesting. Is it possible to evaluate Javascript code through XULRunner?

Comment: oh. I guess we are misunderstanding each other. I thought you wanted to **embed** Spidermonkey, probably by connecting Go with Spidermonkey using C/C++ as a bridge (as that is what spidermonkeys public API uses). the XULRunner SDK provides the necessary headers, import libs and dynamic libraries for this. Or did you intend to use the **standalone interpreter** by calling the executable from Go and run the scripts? The XULRunner SDK still includes the according JS executable (js.exe on Windows). You don't need to use XULRunner, it just happens that the XULRUnner SDK has everything you need.

Comment: @CodeSalad: hm, I think I might have written my question badly - thanks for the clarification. I mean to embed Spidermonkey with C as a bridge, in which case your answer is perfectly correct. Thanks for the help! (If you add it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.)

Also, why is there a close vote? Could that person at least leave a comment (or are they some secret anti-Spidermonkey advocate?)

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer the real question, whether it is safe to run untrustworthy scripts. I have no real security experience, so I can't give an answer on that one. Though I'd say: it depends on what functions and objects you add to the runtime. The normal JS itself should be safe, as it just has a couple of objects like Date (there is nothing like AJAX as all of these browser things come from the DOM and other specs). But if you give the scripts access to the filesystem (by adding according functions using JSAPI to the runtime) then the security obviously depends on your design.